# RxJS : Filter one observable using another observable

Tags: angular, observable, reactive-programming, angular6, rxjs6

I am having one stream which carries the data from the API response and has another stream which emits the values which needs to be filtered from the source stream.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SmpService {
    private _smp$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
    private _deleteSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        const allSmp$ = this.loadSmp().pipe(map(list => list.map(item => item.id)));
        const delete$ = this._deleteSubject.pipe(map(value => this.filterSmp(value)));

        allSmp$
            .pipe(
                combineLatest(delete$, (notifications, xf) => {
                    return xf(notifications);
                }),
                tap(x => console.log('console ', x))
            )
            .subscribe(this._smp$);
    }

    loadSmp(): Observable<any> {
        const contextPath = 'some_url';
        const url = this.uriPrefix + contextPath;
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((response: any) => response.notifications || []));
    }

    filterSmp(value) {
        return notifications => notifications.filter(notification => value !== notification);
    }

    deleteSmp(subscribeItem) {
        this._deleteSubject.next(subscribeItem);
    }

    getSmp(): Observable<any> {
        return this._smp$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Filtering is working fine. But on page load, I am not able to get the initial API response rendered on the page. I only receive that when I trigger the deleteStream via some action.

Is there any way I can get the initial data even though deleteStream is not triggered?

Comment: Maybe be use a `startWith(0)` ?

Comment: @Anas I tried that also. I even thought of triggering the deleteStream manually in the constructor. That would worked, but not the correct solution.

Comment: How are you rendering the API response? Are you pulling the private `_smp$` field in a caller?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Subject` use `BehaviorSubject` with some default value. For example `null`.

```
private _deleteSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

`BehaviorSubject` will emit default value every time it's subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that you're running into is probably that `$delete` is a ["cold"](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) observable until `_deleteSubject` has a value. If you want `_smp$` to be populated before `_deleteSubject` is given any values then you will need to initialize it with a default value, as mentioned by @m1ch4ls.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SmpService {

    private _smp$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
    private _deleteSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        const allSmp$ = this.loadSmp().pipe(map(list => list.map(item => item.id)));
        const delete$ = this._deleteSubject.pipe(map(value => value ? this.filterSmp(value) : (notifications => notifications)));

        delete$
            .pipe(
                withLatestFrom(allSmp$, (xf, notifications) => {
                    return xf(notifications);
                }),
                tap(x => console.log('console ', x))
            )
            .subscribe(this._smp$);
    }

    loadSmp(): Observable<any> {
        const contextPath = 'some_url';
        const url = this.uriPrefix + contextPath;
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((response: any) => response.notifications || []));
    }

    filterSmp(value) {
        return (notifications) => notifications.filter(notification => value !== notification);
    }

    deleteSmp(subscribeItem) {
        this._deleteSubject.next(subscribeItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach of filtering one Observable using another can be

```
    private _smp$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
    private _deleteSubject = new Subject();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        const allSmp$ = this.loadSmp().pipe(map(list => list.map(item => item.id)));
        const delete$ = this._deleteSubject.pipe(
            map(value => (value ? this.filterSmp(value) : notifications => notifications))
        );

        allSmp$.merge(delete$)
            .pipe(
                startWith([]),
                scan((acc, value) => {
                    if (typeof value === 'function') {
                        return [...value(acc)];
                    }
                    return [...acc, ...value];
                })
            )
            .subscribe(this._smp$);
    }
```

In this, we have done following :

1. replaced `BehaviourSubject(null) -> Subject()`
2. replaced `combineLatest -> merge`
3. added `startWith` and `scan` to keep the persistent internal state

And voila, it works. But still looking for other better solutions.